# Communication between Private address class' on same LAN possible?

Tags: networking, winsock-lsp

In my testing, both computers have the same PUBLIC IPV4 address:

```
Two computers bound to the same private class range (192.168.X.X)
PC_0 (192.168.1.2) -> SendsTo -> PC_1 (192.168.1.40) (PC_1 - SUCCESSFULLY RECIEVED MSG)

Two computers bound to the different private class ranges (192.168.X.X) && (172.(16-31).X.X)
PC_0 (192.168.1.2) -> SendsTo -> PC_1 (172.29.3.2)   (PC_1 - FAILED TO RECIVE MSG)
```

Is it possible for two computers on the same private network, but in differnet private class ranges, communicate with each other?

I can't find anything on this specific situation.
Any help or information is appreciated.

Comment: You typically need a router to send packets across different network segments. See [How can I join two networks?](https://superuser.com/questions/461255/).  Alternatively have a look at [How to Connect different class IP's computer in LAN network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r3HaqRb24ME)

Comment: Routers route packets between networks, which is why we have routers. With two different networks, you need a router between them.